Postgres source build with dtrace causing undefined reference linking error
I am working on a custom version of postgres that I was given and I'm trying to build it with the --enable-dtrace option. I imagine there are a number of differences between this version and community (version is more or less in like with 16.4) so it's possible a build file was changed which is causing the problem but I cant track down where and I'm kind of lost right now.
I'm currently receiving the following errors (truncated but all the probes are showing this error):
access/transam/xact.o(.note.stapsdt+0x24): error: undefined reference to 'postgresql_transaction__start_semaphore'
access/transam/xact.o(.note.stapsdt+0x78): error: undefined reference to 'postgresql_transaction__commit_semaphore'
access/transam/xact.o(.note.stapsdt+0xcc): error: undefined reference to 'postgresql_transaction__abort_semaphore'
access/transam/xlog.o(.note.stapsdt+0x24): error: undefined reference to 'postgresql_checkpoint__start_semaphore'
access/transam/xlog.o(.note.stapsdt+0x7c): error: undefined reference to 'postgresql_checkpoint__done_semaphore'

These are created in probes.h as extern which looks correct, but I can't find where they are actually being implemented to find out where my linkage issue could be.
probes.h
/* TRACE_POSTGRESQL_TRANSACTION_COMMIT ( unsigned int ) */
#if defined STAP_SDT_V1
#define TRACE_POSTGRESQL_TRANSACTION_COMMIT_ENABLED() __builtin_expect (transaction__commit_semaphore, 0)
#define postgresql_transaction__commit_semaphore transaction__commit_semaphore
#else
#define TRACE_POSTGRESQL_TRANSACTION_COMMIT_ENABLED() __builtin_expect (postgresql_transaction__commit_semaphore, 0)
#endif
__extension__ extern unsigned short postgresql_transaction__commit_semaphore __attribute__ ((unused)) __attribute__ ((section (".probes")));
#define TRACE_POSTGRESQL_TRANSACTION_COMMIT(arg1) \
DTRACE_PROBE1 (postgresql, transaction__commit, arg1)

Any help on where to look to find where these get implemented or what is causing the linker to not be able to find these symbols would be greatly appreciated!
I tried comparing the makefiles to community and couldn't find any differences. Also built community with the same flags and had no issues so I know my environment has the right tools and my options are correct.

Did you make clean first to remove all generated files?

Since your community build is good with the same parameters, you could start with cleaning both the community package dir and custom package dir to their pristine state (make distclean), then recursively diff those directories ignoring changes in the amount of whitespace (diff -b -r communitydir customdir > diffs.txt ) and study the differences. Are they both git repos? You can arrange to git diff them. Or use a visual diff tool, e.g. Meld.

Yes, make clean was run before each attempt to build.

The community source was downloaded so it's not a git repo. I could clone the git mirror repo and use that. The custom postgres is git.
Would I only have to diff to makefiles? Diffing every file feels like it would be potentially a lot of work since I'm not sure of the scope of the changes in the custom version.

@TreeWater A recursive diff will generate the diffs in negligible time. A graphical diff tool can give you an expandable/collapsible tree-view of the changed/unchanged sub-trees of the directories. You can quickly gauge the scale of the changes and then decide whether its practical or not to dig through them, and where the best candidates are.
